# Elegant/proper way to wrap a python module

Tags: python, wrapper

I'm interested in wrapping pep8 so I can monkey-patch it before use. What is the "right" way to wrap a module?

If my module is named pep8 and lives in my path somewhere before the real pep8, any "import pep8" in my module will just import itself. I don't know in advance where the real pep8 will live, since this needs to be generalized for multiple systems. I can't remove the path where my pep8 wrapper lives from sys.path, because that too will be different depending on the system where it's executed.

I don't want to have to rename my pep8, because I'd like for the pep8 command to work without modification.

My pep8 is a directory containing a `__init__.py` with the following contents:

```
from pep8 import *
MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 119
```

Comment: interesting question re: module monkeypatching, but pep8 is pep8 because it is a standard, even if some of the ideas are designed for circumstances that may occur only infrequently.

Comment: Yeah. We're going to break the 80-column law. It's better to be partially pep8 compliant than not at all, and if I can not have the clutter from the E501 output, that'd make my life a lot easier.

Comment: Why not just alias `pep8` to `python -m pep8 --max-line-length=120` in your shell?

Comment: hur hur! It would probably help if I RTFM and the source. The alias idea may be satisfactory. I still am interested in the problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python 2.5+, you can specify using absolute imports by default. With `from __future__ import absolute_import`.

For monkey patching a Python module, you'll want to do relative imports from your project to your overridden module.

For this example, I will assume you are distributing a library. It requires a little finessing for other projects, since the `__main__` python file cannot have relative imports.

`myproject/__init__.py`:

```
from . import pep8 # optional "as pep8"
# The rest of your code, using this pep8 module.
```

`myproject/pep8/__init__.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from pep8 import *
MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 119
```

Comment: I tried this before I posted. If I ``print dir(pep8)`` after I import, I get: `['MAX_LINE_LENGTH', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'absolute_import']`, which is not the "real" pep8.

Comment: Also, one of my goals is to use the OS-distributed pep8 command without having to modify it. If I have to have to do the above relative import, that's a no-go.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but it still comes up in google searches.  For instances where this is actually desired (ex: protected library wrapping) I suggest the WRAPT package.

I actually use this for instances where I have a model that is part of a core set but can be extended by other applications (such as front-ends like flask apps).  The core model is protected but can be extended by other developers.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wrapt